# How to pass a vector of values to a function?

Tags: r, function, arguments

I've written the following function in R. The output of the function is a coefficient of variation (standard deviation/mean).

```
 CV_concentration <- function(x,cv.tol.raw,A,B,C,D){
 y_at_x <- (A-D)/(1+(x/C)^B)+D
 y_low <- y_at_x * (1-cv.tol.raw/sqrt(2))
 y_high <- y_at_x * (1+cv.tol.raw/sqrt(2))
 x_at_ylow <- C*((A-D)/(y_low-D)-1)^(1/B)
 x_at_yhigh <- C*((A-D)/(y_high-D)-1)^(1/B)
 x_range <- c(x_at_ylow, x_at_yhigh)
 cv_con <- sd(x_range)/mean(x_range)
 return(cv_con)
 }
```

If I were to give a default value to all my arguments except x, my function would be as follows.

```
 CV_concentration <- function(x,cv.tol.raw=0.1,A=100,B=5000,C=5000,D=350000)
```

If I were then to evaluate a single value of X (say x=300), my function would evaluate without a problem; however, I want to test my function at different values of X, without having to call the function each time.

```
 x <- c(400,500)
 CV_concentration(x,cv.tol.raw,A,B,C,D)
```

The above code obviously does not return a vector of values. How can I return a vector of values as output? Please give me some pointers. I tried various apply functions and do.call all to no avail. Thanks.

Comment: Without getting into the guts of your function there is always: `sapply(c(400,500), CV_concentration)`

Comment: see `?Vectorize`

Comment: Thank you so much to both of you. I figured it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `x` is a `num vector`

```
sapply(x, CV_concentration)
```

If `x` is a column in a dataframe `df`

```
sapply(df$x, CV_concentration)
```

Comment: Mike H pretty much said the same. Thanks anyways.